# Split view customization

Tags: lightning-experience, service-cloud-console

Is there any way to add action checkboxes in this split view ?

[image]

Like this one:

[image]

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

The select checkboxes in list views are available when you have inline editing enabled and [details](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customviews_edit_inline_listview_lex_considerations.htm&type=5) around it have been taken care of. However this does not seem to be supported in "Split View" specifically. Split View which was available with Summer '17 also does not mention anything around this in the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_general_lightning_console_split_view.htm). E.g., if you toggle to Table view in your console app, and that you have inline edit enabled, you will be able to see those checkboxes.

Further, if you look at the SLDS of **[Split View](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/split-view/#site-main-content)** from where it is derived from, there's no support for checkboxes (there's no variant other than Base). Whereas if you look the SLDS for **[Data Table](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/#site-main-content)** from which the regular list views are derived, you will be able to see that those design element has specifics around inline edit (toggle between the variants to view the difference).

I could only think of getting it in there with some customization until really supported out of the box.